# How to earn silver in Avengers Alliance?

Tags: marvel-avengers-alliance

I have found that I can earn silver from doing flight deck missions, normal story mode missions, and visiting friend's sections of town.

The problem is that I am not earning enough at a decent rate to keep my heroes training and using time efficiently.

Are there other methods of earning silver so that I can continuously train/research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing for over a month, I've found there to be no other ways to earn silver in the game (aside from paying for it).

The most effective method however is to run constant 3 minute flight deck missions, regardless of level. They bring in the highest amount of return for each passing minute.

[Source/First hand data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArThhiNiW80bdHNoVXRSU21Ic0RzdkVfMHA5WTVlNFE)

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your flight decks - you can get up to a 30% silver bonus (separate from the hero level) -

More info here: http://avengersalliance.wikia.com/wiki/Flight_Deck#Jets